# persist the checkbox selection in the multipage pagination

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am trying to use the javascript for checkbox selection,
my pages are jsp pages, we have pagination but the checkbox selection is not persist when i move from one to another

can you some one help on this

```
   var selectedUnits = [];
             function selectCheckbox(data) {

                if (selectedUnits.length < 1) {
                     selectedUnits.push(data.value);
                 }
                 else {
                     if (data.checked == true) {
                         if ($.inArray(data.value, selectedUnits) < 0) {
                             selectedUnits.push(data.value);
                         }
                         else {
                             selectedUnits.pop(data.value);
                        }
                   }
                    else {
                        selectedUnits.pop(data.value);
                    }

               }

                 console.log(selectedUnits);
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use localStorage
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
becose you need to put the data array out of any navigation
and then "selectedUnits" put into

> localStorage

Expect help you